# Subscriber returning subscriber not info

Tags: angular, observable

I am trying to have access to the result of an http request in my service:

```
  getFriendsProfile(email) {
    return this.http.get(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/profile/' + email);
  }
```

However, console.logging the user profile returns a subscriber but not the information I am looking for. How do I get the info?

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userProfile = this.userService.getUserProfile().subscribe((res) => {
      this.userProfile = res;
    });
    console.log(this.userProfile);
  }
```

Comment: Maybe this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not set the userProfile to the subscription, instead only set it in the subscription callback.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.userService.getUserProfile().subscribe((res) => {
    this.userProfile = res;
    console.log(this.userProfile);
  });
}
```

Comment: your answer is correct, however you have typed `Do not set the userProfile to the subscription, instead only set it in the subscription callback.`. Correctly is do not use console.log outside of subscription but only inside as there it will be called with the value c orrectly

Comment: If you set this.userProfile = this.userService.getUserProfile().subscribe(...) you are not setting it to the result but rather the returned subscription. There is more going on here than moving a console log.